# Can i publish apps in google market in many language?

Tags: android, google-play

Can i publish apps in google market in many language only change the name of application and the application has only one language

Answer (score 1):

You even don't have to change the name of the application, you can add several languages to your app and decide by your system settings which language is selected.

See http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html